# Boolean expression question

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra

So im kinda curious which this would be. I have a question to turn a Boolean expression into a logic circuit which I have no issues doing but im a little confused about this question. I will leave an image below of the expression and also the circuit I feel like it is, im just confused whether (A.B) is AND or NAND as I am not sure if the line above everything is for the + only or for the first brackets too.[image]

The image above is how I see the circuit

Comment: @vicatcu Yes the only reason I got a little confused was due to the line above the whole expression which at first I thought was only for the OR gate but just wanted to double check and make sure my original layout was correct, appreciate the quick response also

Comment: yea the over-bar applies to as many of the terms that it covers.You can, of course, use De Morgan's Law to move the negations around.

Answer (score 1):

A dot is one traditional symbol for AND in Boolean notation. If it were NAND, it would have an over-bar over the dotted terms. Similarly, plus is one traditional symbol for OR, and the usual companion to dot for AND, and NOR would typically be expressed as an over-bar over the plussed terms. So, I think your answer looks like a faithful implementation of the expression.

The other common symbols that are used are ^ for AND and v for OR.